# Spark: calling a function inside of mapPartitionsWithIndex

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I got very strange results with the following code. 
I only want to take the partition data and iterate for each data, X times.

Here I'm calling to my function for each partition:

```
val myRDDResult = myRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex( myFunction(_, _, limit), preservesPartitioning = true)
```

And the funcion is:

```
private def myFunction (partitionIndex: Long,
                          partitionData: Iterator[Array[(LabeledPoint,Int,Int)]]), limit: Int): Iterator[String] = {

    var newData = ArrayBuffer[String]()
    if (partitionData.nonEmpty){
        val partDataMap = partitionData.next.map{ case (lp, _, neighId) => (lp, neighId) }.toMap
        var newString:String = ""
        for {
            (k1,_) <- partDataMap
            i  <- 0 to limit
            _ = {
             // ... some code to generate the content for `newString`
            newData.+=(newString)
           }
        }yield ()
    } 
    newData.iterator
}
```

Here are some values obtained:

```
partitionData   limit   newData   newData_expected
```

```
1640            250     411138   410000 (1640*250)
16256           27      288820   438912
```

I don't know if I misundertanding some concept of my code.

I've also tried changing the `for` part for this idea: `partDataMap.map{elem=> for (i <- 0 to limit){....}}`

Any suggestions?

Comment: we cannot help you without sample data and the complete implementation of myFunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, sorry because I downvoted/upvoted (click error) your question and since I didn't cancel it within 10 minutes, SO kept it upvoted.

Regarding to your code, I think your expected results are bad because I took the same code as you, simplified it a little, and instead of receiving *410000* elements, I got *411640*. Maybe I copied something incorrectly or ignore some stuff, but the code giving 411640 looks like:

```
val limit = 250
val partitionData: Iterator[Array[Int]] = Seq((1 to 1640).toArray).toIterator
var newData = ArrayBuffer[String]()
if (partitionData.nonEmpty){
  val partDataMap = partitionData.next.map{ nr => nr.toString }

  for {
    value <- partDataMap
    i  <- 0 to limit
    _ = {
      newData.+=(s"${value}_${i}")
    }
  } yield ()
}
println(s"new buffer=${newData}")
println(s"Buffer size =  ${newData.size}")
```

Now to answer to your question about why `mapWithPartitions` results differ from your expectations. IMO it's because your conversion from the `Array` to `Map`. If in your array you have duplicated key, it will count only once. It could explain why in both cases (if we consider 411640 as correct expected number) you receive the results lower than expected. To be sure of that you can compare `partDataMap.size` with `partitionData.next.size`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code is right, but the _expected_ result has to be _410000_ (because of 1640*250). I think it could be the Array to Map conversion, as you said. I'll check it!

Comment: No, it's correct but it's not 1640*250 but 1640*251. It's because you do `i  <- 0 to limit` instead of `i  <- 0 until limit` (including last index/excluding last index). Thus my theory about duplicated keys in the map is quite probable. Add the comparison in between input's array size and the map size to see.

Comment: Yes, you were right!!! Instead of `partDataMap` I have used `partitionData`, and I got the correct result. And I also change `to` for `until`. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't mind, @bartosz25,  I want to ask you how do you think about the performance to apply a `for` over an `Iterator` instead of a `Map`.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting exercise. For your last question, in Scala `yield` doesn't behave the same as in Python. The values are not computed lazily. So IMO it shouldn't have any significant difference. I didn't check it though and if you have some time, maybe you can run your processing 10 times (or +) for both versions and compare the execution times to get the best option.